# API calls made in Ionic 4 app not working on Android device

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework, ionic4

I am able to run my ionic app on my laptop by using the `ionic lab` command.

The app makes calls to the IMDB api, & displays data retrieved from it.

Now, I am trying to run the app on an android device.
by using the following command: `ionic cordova run android --device`.

The app appears on my phone, but when I search for IMDB data, no results are appearing.

Below is the service I am using to make calls to the API:

```
export class MovieService {

  url = 'http://www.omdbapi.com/';
  apiKey = 'myKey';

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  searchData(title: string, type: SearchType): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.get(`${this.url}?s=${encodeURI(title)}&type=${type}&apikey=${this.apiKey}`)
      .pipe(
        map(results => {
          console.log('RAW', results);
          return results['Search'];
        })
      );
  }

  getDetails(id): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.get(`${this.url}?i=${id}&plot=full&apikey=${this.apiKey}`);
  }
}
```

Can someone please tell me why the app is working on my laptop, but when I try to use it on my phone it isn't working as expected?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Probably one reason is that you are using `http` not `https`.

Android restricted access to non-secure feeds in a recent security update.

Try:

```
url = 'https://www.omdbapi.com/';
```

Comment: is there any way to fix this? ionic not working on http requests.

Comment: yes you can [allow cleartext using some settings](https://medium.com/@imstudio/android-8-cleartext-http-traffic-not-permitted-73c1c9e3b803).

Comment: yes i was able to make that work using the settings cleartext