# Modify AndroidManifest.xml in ionic project

Tags: android, angular, cordova, ionic-framework

I've got to add these following line in my AndroidManifest.xml :

```
<network-security-config>
    <base-config cleartextTrafficPermitted="true">
        <trust-anchors>
            <certificates src="system" />
        </trust-anchors>
    </base-config>
</network-security-config>
```

I add this in my project_path/config.xml :

```
<edit-config file="app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml" mode="merge" target="/manifest/application" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
            <application android:networkSecurityConfig="@xml/network_security_config" />
            <network-security-config>
                <base-config cleartextTrafficPermitted="true">
                    <trust-anchors>
                        <certificates src="system" />
                    </trust-anchors>
                </base-config>
            </network-security-config>
        </edit-config>
```

but my AndroidManifest.xml isn't modified when I execute `ionic cordova build android`

Comment: But why you want to add the complete tag only android:networkSecurityConfig="@xml/network_security_config" should be added to the application tag. and the rest should go to android xml folder

Comment: I must call an api on a server, but it haven't https protocol, I saw this post : `https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57433362/api-calls-made-in-ionic-4-app-not-working-on-android-device` according to that http request in android are restricted access

Comment: what is your api protocol http or https?

Comment: My api protocol is http

Comment: have you tried using android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"

Comment: `<application android:networkSecurityConfig="@xml/network_security_config" android:supportsRtl="true" android:usesCleartextTraffic="true">` I've got this line in my AndroidManifest.xml but the connection with my api not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`networkSecurityConfig` isn't loading its config directly from config.xml. It's in an separated XML file. 
It is from `ressources/android/xml/network_security_config.xml` file (as the line `<application android:networkSecurityConfig="@xml/network_security_config" />` state in config.xml)

Put the following in ressources/android/xml/network_security_config.xml:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<network-security-config>
  <base-config cleartextTrafficPermitted="true">
    <trust-anchors>
      <certificates src="system" />
    </trust-anchors>
  </base-config>
</network-security-config>
```

Then run

```sh
ionic cordova prepare
```

Now into `platforms/android/app/src/main/res/xml/network_security_config.xml` you will see that your config got updated accordingly.

Comment: I've got this in my network_sercurity_config.xml : ``` 
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<network-security-config>
    <domain-config cleartextTrafficPermitted="true">
        <domain includeSubdomains="true">localhost</domain>
    </domain-config>
</network-security-config>```

Comment: ```
I just replace with your lines or like that :
```<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<network-security-config>
    <domain-config cleartextTrafficPermitted="true">
        <domain includeSubdomains="true">localhost</domain>
    </domain-config>
    <base-config cleartextTrafficPermitted="true">
        <trust-anchors>
            <certificates src="system" />
        </trust-anchors>
    </base-config>
</network-security-config>```

Comment: config got updated like you want when running `ionic cordova prepare`?

Comment: did my post help you ?

Comment: Yes, when I'm running `ionic cordova prepare` config is updated but my app still jot receiving datas from my api, so I did a new https server to welcome it

Comment: Cool! Why don't you open an other question for that ? I will be happy to help. 
By the way, I would really appreciate if you would validate my answer. As you said, your config got updated. It's not encouraging to answers questions and to not receive points :(

Comment: Just want to thanks Ismod for helping me out. Encounter samilar error while migrating from Ionic 3 to 4. I think it's related to the http issue as Android restricted to use http but for development in my case, this solution saved me time updating the SSL because it's just for development and coding.

Comment: This answer is somewhat incomplete as of the current version of things. In addition to adding the ```<application android:networkSecurityConfig="@xml/network_security_config" />``` to the ```<edit-config>``` node, I also had to add the file as an actual resource to the ```<platform>``` : ```<resource-file src="resources/android/xml/network_security_config.xml" target="app/src/main/res/xml/network_security_config.xml" />```

Answer (score 0):

In ionic 7 it works a little bit different. Instead of writing it to config.xml you should write it to capcitor.config.ts/js under cordova:

```
const config = {

... 

  cordova: {
    preferences: {
      'android-minSdkVersion': '22',
      'android-compileSdkVersion': '29',
      'android-targetSdkVersion': '29',
      'android:requestLegacyExternalStorage': 'true',
    },
  },
};
```